# Why does my rule always redirect even though I put [L]?

Tags: mod-rewrite

Here's my `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* index.php?url=$0 [L]
```

And my `index.php` file:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
```

When I go to `mysite/cat` I get:

```
array
  'url' => string 'index.php' (length=9)
```

Which suggests that it redirects twice, and `index.php` is getting stuffed into `url`. I thought `[L]` was supposed to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `L`flag does prevent further `RewriteRule`s from being applied for the current request, but if an external redirect occurs then the entire set of rules will be re-entered from the top again regardless.

Comment: So what's the best way of stopping it then? `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index.php`?

Comment: That's one way. Another is to use to conditions with `-f` and `-d` to not redirect away from things that may actually exist.